# How to find computer object OU from server itself using CMD

Tags: powershell, command-line, active-directory, ou

How can I find what OU the computer belongs to using CMD or powershell cmdlet . I have found some long scripts but there has to be a one liner command for it.
The computers dont have AD role installed on them so DSQUERY is out of equation.
CMD or powershell cmdlet would work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A one-liner for PowerShell without AD Role would be:

```
([adsisearcher]"(&(name=$env:computername)(objectClass=computer))").findall().path
```

That would give you a string like:

```
LDAP://CN=MyComputer,OU=Workstations,OU=Machines,DC=TacoTruck,DC=com
```

That would work on the local computer. If you want to run against a remote server on the same domain replace `$env:computername` with the name of the computer.

Comment: Add `-replace '^.*?(?=OU=)'` or access `parent` (might need to get directoryentry first), and you're done. :-)